# Querying A Post That Includes Two Taxonomies Using JSON Rest API

Tags: wp-query, json, plugin-json-api, rest-api

I'm using the JSON Rest API plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/). I have two custom taxonomies with one term each:

1. Inner Part Categories

   - Eye
2. Symptoms Categories (Man)

   - Broken Bone Single Fracture

I need to show posts that match both of these categories and terms. I've tried the following:

```
http://mcsc.hawkhorne.com/wp-json/posts?type=male-conditions&filter[taxonomy]=inner-part-categories&filter[term]=Eye&filter[taxonomy]=symptoms-categories-man&filter[term]=Broken%20Bone%20Single%20Fracture
```

But this method only returns the posts under the last declared taxonomy and term. For example, if I switch the tax and term around as such:

```
http://mcsc.hawkhorne.com/wp-json/posts?type=male-conditions&filter[taxonomy]=symptoms-categories-man&filter[term]=Broken%20Bone%20Single%20Fracture&filter[taxonomy]=inner-part-categories&filter[term]=Eye
```

It will then only show posts under the tax inner-part-categories and term Eye and ignore the first tax and term query.

I've been searching for hours and having found a solution.

I was also thinking maybe an array of sorts could be passed in the ajax data request, sort of how it's done in WP Query. I have the following code:

> data: {
>   filter: {
>   'posts_per_page': -1,
>   'post_status': 'publish',
>   'orderby': 'title',
>   'order': 'ASC'
>   }
>   },

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your problem with the last post type and/or term overwriting all previous is because 'filter' is a 2-dimensional array. Therefore 'taxonomy' (the key in this case) can only have one value.  If that seems odd, read this super helpful page on the plugin's github that helped me a lot ([read this](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/blob/1965084978ddc43787dbc64c02f0565dbd837c53/docs/compatibility.md))

tldr; term lists and multi-dimensional arrays are possible with WP JSON API!  you would just do `type[]=post_type1&type[]=post_type2` for custom post types!  Try it.

So, with that in mind... you still can't do a multiple custom taxonomy query currently (as far as I can tell).  Bummer, I know.  My solution?  Nest your second query within the success callback of the first, then concatenate the arrays and sort the final array.

```
$http.get(
  $scope.api + '/posts?type=eats&filter[taxonomy]=eats-categories&filter[term]=eats-video'
).
success(function(data, status, headers, config){
  $scope.posts = data;
    $http.get(
      $scope.api + '/posts?type=shreds&filter[taxonomy]=shreds-categories&filter[term]=shreds-video'
    ).
    success(function(data_2, status, headers, config){
      $scope.posts = $scope.posts.concat( data_2 );
    }).
    error(function(data_2, status, headers, config){
        alert( 'video 2 widget query error' );
    });     
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config){
    alert( 'video widget query error' );
});
```

Note, this code is specific to my queries, but I tested it and it worked.  I haven't written the sort function yet, but I'll either be sorting by the WordPress date field of the array values or using an angular filter to do something fun.

Edit: made a couple of changes for clarity.